# Adding Descriptive Statistic results in a boxplot by means of function aggregate in R

Tags: r, aggregate, boxplot, usage-statistics

I have the following information:

`head(Callao20)`

```
  Day Mes  Aho Temp
1  12 Feb 2020   NA
2  12 Feb 2020   NA
3  12 Feb 2020   NA
4  12 Feb 2020   NA
5  12 Feb 2020   NA
6  12 Feb 2020   NA
```

Knowing that `cv = (sd/mean)*100`, then I estimated the cv as following:

```
aggregate(Callao20[, 4], list(Callao20$Mes), 
          function(x) (sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)/mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))*100)
```

How can the mean sd or cv be added in my boxplot?

```
boxplot(Temp~Mes, data=Callao20)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should always provide reproducible data with your question. It is recommended and you will get your answer faster. Here is a data set that is included in R. It consists of measurements of flowers, but it is organized similarly to yours:

```
data(iris)
str(iris)
# 'data.frame': 150 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
#  $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
#  $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
#  $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
#  $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

We will construct boxplots by `Species` for the first measurement, `Sepal.Length`. First we need the statistics:

```
cvs <- aggregate(Sepal.Length~Species, iris, function(x) sd(x)/mean(x)*100)
cvs
#      Species Sepal.Length
# 1     setosa        7.041
# 2 versicolor        8.696
# 3  virginica        9.652
range(iris$Sepal.Length)
# [1] 4.3 7.9
```

We need the range in `Sepal.Length` to make enough space on the plot for the statistics:

```
boxplot(Sepal.Length~Species, iris, ylim=c(4.1, 8.1))
par("usr")[3:4]
# [1] 3.94 8.26
```

The bottom of the plot is at 3.94 and the top is at 8.26 so we plot the statistics a little above the bottom or a little below the top:

```
text(1:3, rep(4.1, 3), round(cvs$Sepal.Length, 2))
text(1:3, rep(8.1, 3), round(cvs$Sepal.Length, 2))
```

You did not say where you wanted to print the values this example puts them above and below. [image: Boxplot]